# Creating a Custom Data Adapter: Importing data adapter

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Following the tutorial for creating a custom data adapter:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/advanced_topics/custom_data_adapter/

Getting error in chrome console:
[image]

Created file Hyperion.Data.BimapiDataAdapter in the folder forge-dataviz-iot-reference-app-main\node_modules\forge-dataviz-iot-data-modules\client\data based on the Hyperion.Data.Adapter file in the same folder. Then edited on line 371 and changed RestApiDataAdapter to BimapiDataAdapter.

[image]

Then trying to import this in BaseApp.jsx on line 34 in the folder forge-dataviz-iot-reference-app-main\node_modules\forge-dataviz-iot-react-components\client\components.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Hyperion.Data.BimapiDataAdapter.js` is not placed aside `forge-dataviz-iot-react-components/BaseApp.jsx`, so the package-tool [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) cannot it by `./Hyperion.Data.BimapiDataAdapter` in `BaseApp.jsx`.

Here is my approach to exposing `Hyperion.Data.BimapiDataAdapter.js`.

1. Create `Hyperion.Data.BimapiDataAdapter.js` under `forge-dataviz-iot-reference-app-main\node_modules\forge-dataviz-iot-data-modules\client\data`. Here is how it looks like (just copied and pasted the contents of `RestApiDataAdapter` for the quick demo)

```js
import { DataAdapter } from './Hyperion.Data';

/**
 * Data adapter class dealing with sample data.
 * @memberof Autodesk.DataVisualization.Data
 * @alias Autodesk.DataVisualization.Data.BimapiDataAdapter
 * @augments DataAdapter
 */
 export class BimapiDataAdapter extends DataAdapter {
    /**
     * Constructs an instance of BimapiDataAdapter.
     */
    constructor(provider = "synthetic", baseName = "") {
        super("BimapiDataAdapter", baseName);
        /* eslint-disable no-undef */
        this._provider = provider;
    }

    /**
     * Loads all DeviceModel objects from the sample REST API.
     *
     * @returns {Promise<DeviceModel[]>} A promise that resolves to a single
     * &nbsp;dimensional array containing a list of loaded DeviceModel objects. If no
     * &nbsp;DeviceModel is available, the promise resolves to an empty array.
     * @memberof Autodesk.DataVisualization.Data
     * @alias Autodesk.DataVisualization.Data.BimapiDataAdapter#loadDeviceModels
     */
    async loadDeviceModels() {
        const adapterId = this.id;
        return fetch(this._getResourceUrl("api/device-models"))
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((rawDeviceModels) => {
                /** @type {DeviceModel[]} */
                const normalizedDeviceModels = [];

                rawDeviceModels.forEach((rdm) => {
                    // Create a normalized device model representation.
                    const ndm = new DeviceModel(rdm.deviceModelId, adapterId);
                    ndm.name = rdm.deviceModelName;
                    ndm.description = rdm.deviceModelDesc;

                    // Generate device property representation.
                    rdm.deviceProperties.forEach((rdp) => {
                        const propId = rdp.propertyId;
                        const propName = rdp.propertyName;

                        const ndp = ndm.addProperty(propId, propName);
                        ndp.description = rdp.propertyDesc;
                        ndp.dataType = rdp.propertyType;
                        ndp.dataUnit = rdp.propertyUnit;
                        ndp.rangeMin = rdp.rangeMin ? rdp.rangeMin : undefined;
                        ndp.rangeMax = rdp.rangeMax ? rdp.rangeMax : undefined;
                    });

                    normalizedDeviceModels.push(ndm);
                });

                // Fetch actual devices for each of the device models.
                return this.fetchDevicesForModels(normalizedDeviceModels);
            });
    }

    /**
     * Fetches actual device IDs and populate DeviceModel objects with them.
     *
     * @param {DeviceModel[]} deviceModels The DeviceModel objects for which
     * &nbsp;actual device IDs are to be populated.
     *
     * @returns {Promise<DeviceModel[]>} A promise that resolves to the
     * &nbsp;DeviceModel objects populated with actual device IDs.
     * @memberof Autodesk.DataVisualization.Data
     * @alias Autodesk.DataVisualization.Data.BimapiDataAdapter#fetchDevicesForModels
     */
    async fetchDevicesForModels(deviceModels) {
        const promises = deviceModels.map((deviceModel) => {
            const model = deviceModel.id;
            return fetch(this._getResourceUrl("api/devices", { model: model }))
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((jsonData) => jsonData.deviceInfo);
        });

        return Promise.all(promises).then((deviceInfosList) => {
            // Assign devices to each device model.
            deviceModels.forEach((deviceModel, index) => {
                // Turn data provider specific device data format into
                // the unified data format stored in Device object.
                //
                const deviceInfos = deviceInfosList[index];
                deviceInfos.forEach((deviceInfo) => {
                    const device = deviceModel.addDevice(deviceInfo.id);
                    device.name = deviceInfo.name;

                    const p = deviceInfo.position;
                    device.position = new THREE.Vector3(
                        parseFloat(p.x),
                        parseFloat(p.y),
                        parseFloat(p.z)
                    );

                    device.lastActivityTime = deviceInfo.lastActivityTime;
                    device.deviceModel = deviceModel;
                    device.sensorTypes = deviceModel.propertyIds;
                });
            });

            return deviceModels;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Fetches the property data based on the given device ID.
     *
     * @param {QueryParam} query Parameters of this query.
     *
     * @returns {Promise<DeviceData>} A promise that resolves to an aggregated
     * &nbsp;property data for the queried device.
     * @memberof Autodesk.DataVisualization.Data
     * @alias Autodesk.DataVisualization.Data.BimapiDataAdapter#fetchDeviceData
     */
    async fetchDeviceData(query) {
        const pids = query.propertyIds;
        const promises = pids.map((pid) => this._fetchPropertyData(query, pid));

        return Promise.all(promises).then((deviceDataList) => {
            const deviceData = new DeviceData(query.deviceId);
            deviceDataList.forEach((devData) => deviceData.mergeFrom(devData));
            return deviceData;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Fetches data for a single property based on the given device ID.
     *
     * @param {QueryParam} query Parameters of this query.
     * @param {string} propertyId The ID of the property.
     *
     * @returns {Promise<DeviceData>} A promise that resolves to an aggregated
     * &nbsp;property data for the queried device.
     */
    async _fetchPropertyData(query, propertyId) {
        const url = this._getResourceUrl("api/aggregates", {
            device: query.deviceId,
            property: propertyId,
            startTime: query.dateTimeSpan.startSecond,
            endTime: query.dateTimeSpan.endSecond,
            resolution: query.dateTimeSpan.resolution,
        });

        return fetch(url)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((rawAggregates) => {
                // Convert 'rawAggregates' which is in the following format, into 'AggregatedValues'
                //
                // rawAggregates = {
                //     timestamps: number[],
                //     count: number[],
                //     min: number[],
                //     max: number[],
                //     avg: number[],
                //     sum: number[],
                //     stdDev: number[]
                // }
                //
                const aggrValues = new AggregatedValues(query.dateTimeSpan);
                aggrValues.tsValues = rawAggregates.timestamps;
                aggrValues.countValues = rawAggregates.count;
                aggrValues.maxValues = rawAggregates.max;
                aggrValues.minValues = rawAggregates.min;
                aggrValues.avgValues = rawAggregates.avg;
                aggrValues.sumValues = rawAggregates.sum;
                aggrValues.stdDevValues = rawAggregates.stdDev;
                aggrValues.setDataRange("avgValues", getPaddedRange(aggrValues.avgValues));

                const deviceData = new DeviceData(query.deviceId);
                const propertyData = deviceData.getPropertyData(propertyId);
                propertyData.setAggregatedValues(aggrValues);

                return deviceData;
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(err);
            });
    }

    /**
     * Gets the resource URL for a given endpoint with query parameters
     *
     * @param {string} endpoint The endpoint for the URL to generate
     * @param {Object.<string, string>} parameters Key-value pairs of query parameters
     *
     * @returns {string} The string that represents the complete resource URL
     * @private
     */
    _getResourceUrl(endpoint, parameters) {
        parameters = parameters || {};

        parameters["provider"] = this._provider;
        parameters["project"] = "unused";
        const ps = Object.entries(parameters).map(([k, v]) => `${k}=${v}`);
        return `${this._baseName}/${endpoint}?${ps.join("&")}`;
    }
}
```

2. Expose the class `BimapiDataAdapter` from ``forge-dataviz-iot-reference-app-main\node_modules\forge-dataviz-iot-data-modules\client.js`

```js
export * from "./client/data/Hyperion.Data";
export * from "./client/data/Hyperion.Data.BimapiDataAdapter"; //!<<< add this line
```

3. Import `BimapiDataAdapter` in `forge-dataviz-iot-reference-app-main\node_modules\forge-dataviz-iot-react-components\client\components\BaseApp.jsx` from where `import { ... } from "forge-dataviz-iot-data-modules/client"` is

```js
import {
    Session,
    AzureDataAdapter,
    RestApiDataAdapter,
    DataView,
    DateTimeSpan,
    EventType,
    DeviceProperty,
    DeviceModel,
    BimapiDataAdapter //!<<< here it is
} from "forge-dataviz-iot-data-modules/client";
```

Afterward, re-execute `ENV=local npm run dev` in your terminal console.

If you have further questions on how Webpack resolves packages, I would advise you to check these out:

- https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/
- https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/